# How to form a sql query for the following result?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, join, subquery

[image: Schema]

This is a example schema which can be used to attain my result.

Here, Customer -  PurchaseHistory is 1:N relationship. A custom can have n number of purchases.

PurchaseHistory -  Product 1:1 relationship. Each purchase consist of only one product.

Desired Result :

Display the customer who has purchased both Product1 and product2 or just product3.

Sample Data :

Customer

[image: customer table]

PurchaseHistory :

[image: purchase History]

Product1

[image: product1]

Product2
[image: product2]

Expected answer :  Customer c2 as he has purchased both product1 and product2.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)'

Comment: First of all, are products 1,2 and 3 really tables or are these example tuples of your table Product? In the latter you can achive you goal by simply left join those 3 tables and then add the where condtions checking NULL values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select customer_id from purchasehistory t
Where (t.purchese_id in (select purchese_id from product1) 
And t.purchese_id in (t.purchese_id in (select purchese_id from product2))
Or t.purchese_id in (t.purchese_id in (select purchese_id from product1)
```

This will work , though your table scheme should change , you don’t want a table for each product , it works in a world of 3 products , not in 100.

Comment: Actually my schema is completely different and a enterprise design as well. As i cannot post that one here, i tried to design one sample that solves my query.

Comment: My problem is, I will have a primary module which is exposed. And there will be sub modules in that primary module. I need to apply filter on each of the sub modules and logically combine these filters to get records from primary module. I need some template query such that i can construct for all this same kind of relation.

Comment: @AravindAshok on a high level filter - I would suggest joining all of these ‘products’ into 1 query, and join that query with your main data . On basic filter , I would use the in method like I showed on my example

Comment: yeah thats the problem. If i join all the tables, in this case each customer row has multiple purchase history rows. And then i join this result with each product table applying some filter on each product as join condition. Now,  each row has detail about only one of three products. And i am wondering how to filter only the customer  according to the above condition.

Answer (score 0):

I have written one query for you. It is not tested with actual data. But I have written with your requirement. Play with and make some changes and try it on mysql console with you have. See if you can achieve your desired result.

```
select c.name from purchasehistory ph
left join customer c on ph.customerid = c.customer_id
join product1 p1 on ph.purchase_id = p1.purchase_id
join product2 p2 on ph.purchase_id = p2.purchase_id
join prodcut3 p3 on ph.purchase_id = p3.purchase_id
where (p1.purchase_id is not null and p2.purchase_id is not null) 
or p3.purchase_id is not null
```

Comment: the join of product1, 2 and 3 should by left joins, otherwise you imply that p1.purchase_id (and p2, p3 aswell) are always not null.

Comment: This wont work as each row of purchase history will match with only one row of three product tables. So every row will contain entries for only one of three product table and applying your where clause wont work.